# Cant run vite project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, vite

Yesterday I started a Vite project and closed it now I opened it again but when I run 'npm run dev' I get an error so I cant run my project I am using Vite with react and typescript.

Here is a picture of the error I would appreciate help because I have no idea how to fix this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Paste the error text in the post, it will be hard for people to find this post if they have a similar issue. Also, did you view the log file? Do you actually have a `package.json` file in your root `chat/` directory? Pretty sure this is not a Vite issue, sounds like a node/npm issue.

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory where the project is and try (npm init) then (npm install) and wait after that (npm run dev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Make sure you are in the directory where the project is and try (npm init) then (npm install) and wait after that (npm run dev)" is the solution that worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like an issue with node. Check if the json file is within the chat directory.